# Visual Studio Code - Add multiple commands

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing my first VSC extension with this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).

The "extension.ts" contains a hello world command.

I want to add another command `git_open_modified_files`, but it is not described in the tutorial how it is done.

I just added this to my **package.json**:

```
...
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "git-open-modified-files.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "command": "git-open-modified-files.git_open_modified_files",
        "title": "Git open modified files"
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

#### extension.ts

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "git-open-modified-files" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('git-open-modified-files.helloWorld', () => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from Git_Open_Modified_Files!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);

    let disposable2 = vscode.commands.registerCommand('git-open-modified-files.git_open_modified_files', () => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World 2 from Git_Open_Modified_Files!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable2);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

But if I call the command I get

[image]

Comment: you have to add that new command to the `activation` list in `package.json`

Comment: That looks good to me, so I wonder if the extension is not rebuilt somehow, before you start debugging.

Comment: @MikeLischke, I just pressed on "Run Extension" respectively on F5, like described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but I stumbled upon the same issue and fixed it by adding the entry inside the `"activationEvents"` in package.json.

So

```yaml
"activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:git-open-modified-files.helloWorld",
        "onCommand:git-open-modified-files.git_open_modified_files"
    ],
```